# What do fragment and width mean in audioop.rms(fragment, width)

Tags: python-3.x, audio, wav

I am trying to analyze a wav file in python and get the rms value from the wav.  I am using audioop.rms to get the value from the wav.  I went to do this and I did not know what fragment and width stood for.  I am new to audioop and hope somebody can explain this.  I am also wondering if there is any better way to do this in python.

Update: I have done some research and I found out fragment stood for the wav file.  I still need to figure out what width means.

Answer (score 4):

A fragment is just a chunk of data. Width is the size in bytes that the data is organized. ex 8bits data has width 1, 16bits has 2 and so on.

```

```
import alsaaudio, audioop
self.input = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE,alsaaudio.PCM_NONBLOCK)
self.input.setchannels(1)
self.input.setrate(8000) 
self.input.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
self.input.setperiodsize(300)
length, data = self.input.read()
avg_i = audioop.avg(data,2)
```

```
In the example i am setting alsa capture card to use a S16_LE signed 16bits Little Endian, so I have to set width to be 2. For the fragment is just the data captured by alsa. In your case the wav file is your data.